# Is building a self contained docker container the correct production way to do it

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2

I have inherited the task of my previous devOps to correct any mistakes he has made.

Currently our PHP developers are deploying their APP inside a docker container composed of the following inside their dockerfile:

- PHP-5.6fpm or PHP-7.0-fpm as base
- install their php extensions
- install nginx-lite
- install supervisord
- copy nginx.conf
- copy supervisor.conf

inside supervisor we would have 2 commands: one for nginx and one for php.
supervisor then becomes the default CMD at the end of the Dockerfile.

the /app directory inside the container is where a copy of the Application lives.

We deployed on a m3 AWS ec2 server and launch the container. Inside the ec2 server there is nginx that is listening to a certain port. We have attached a LB to listen to the container of the application's port mapping: ie app1 is on port 8001, app2 is on port 8002, etc. Any "DB" we use other servers to service the app (ie RDS for db, redis is done by elatic-cache, etc).

Currently these containers are working - however - I am wondering if it is working via hack and slash and if these containers are actually proper.

Question:
- was my previous devops correct in creating the application container?
- if the answer is no what would be the correct way that it should have been built in order to achieve a proper production docker deployment where we would eventually put Kubernetes

Answer (score 0):

Well that's definitely wrong and beats Docker purpose. It should be one application / service per container, however, in your case you've got all 1 container. I would suggest that you split the services into specific containers.

Moreover, you wouldn't build the containers to push to production. They should already be build in the previous environment whatever that might be (pre-prod, development, test).

The way you've got it now it will make it difficult to scale as well as you are wasting time in building the containers each time for each environment as well as sometimes doing so might get out of sync as you can build the development / test / pre-prod containers in a way and different in production.

Comment: So in reality:
containers should be built on the environment server that it is running. the application itself should use the container via volume instead of being copied over inside the container and each dependencies (services) should be built independently - correct?

Comment: Well in practice varies on what environments you've got / want to have. However, as far as I am aware you would have a development and a testing environment at least. You build the containers in the development environment or you have a Jenkins / Gitlab CI job which does that. Here you've got 2 options, one you add the data inside the container you are building, or you add the data in a volume so you will be able to scale. If you need to use Nginx, Redis, Apache, DB, NPM or any other service, you will need to have separate containers for each of them